# Distinguish real Windows directories from "backward compability" ones with node.js

Tags: node.js, windows

The `fs.readdir()` method on my (German) Windows 10 lists "Programme" as a directory in `C:\`.

This is of course one of the famous "fake" directories (just as `C:\Documents and Settings`) linking to `C:\Program Files` to preserve backwards compability for programs developed to be installed under Windows XP.

Problem is that I have no way to distinguish this kind of directory from a "real" one.

- `fs.statsSync("C:\\Programme").isDirectory()` returns `true`
- `fs.statsSync("C:\\Programme").isSymbolicLink()` returns `false`
- `fs.accessSync("C:\\Programme", fs.F_OK)` returns `true`
- `fs.readdirSync("C:\\Programme")` throws

So the only way I found to distinguish those folders is to read their contents which sounds like a waste of resources to me, even more so if I want to do this for every directory in `C:\`.

Is there any other reliable way to do this?

Comment: Looking at the node.js docs, would [fs.realpath](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_options_callback) return the actual path of the special directory name? And a comparison of the actual path vs the input path (special directory name) could determine whether or not the input path was the actual path (?).

Comment: Wow, that was unexpectedly easy. You're right, `realpath()` returns `C:\Program Files` in this case thus making the distinction possible. I didn't even think of applying it to a non-relative path. Thank you!

Comment: The reason why `isSymbolicLink` is false is because it's indeed no symlink but a junction point (which you can see when use `dir /a c:\ `). The way it works is that the directory is set up as junction point to the real one, but the junction point self gets the hidden attribute and gets an ACL set which allows nobody access to the directory (only to contents in it). This means you can use `dir c:\programme\internet explorer` but not `dir c:\programme` - this should prevent users from using the fake directories but allow accesses to contents of the "wrong" path" transparently.

Comment: Yeah I knew it's actually not symlinks they used to realize this feature but I couldn't find the actual technique used. Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as my comment (which was a bit of a guess that turned out to be correct), I'm posting here as the actual answer since no other answers have been provided.

The [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) document the [fs.realpath](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_options_callback) method as an asynchronous version of the [realpath(3) method](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) which states:

> **Description**:
>   realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./,
>   /../ and extra '/' characters in the null-terminated string named by
>   path to produce a canonicalized absolute pathname.  The resulting
>   pathname is stored as a null-terminated string, up to a maximum of
>   PATH_MAX bytes, in the buffer pointed to by resolved_path.  The
>   resulting path will have no symbolic link, /./ or /../ components.
>
> If resolved_path is specified as NULL, then realpath() uses malloc(3)
>   to allocate a buffer of up to PATH_MAX bytes to hold the resolved
>   pathname, and returns a pointer to this buffer.  The caller should
>   deallocate this buffer using free(3).
>
> **Return Value**
>   If there is no error, realpath() returns a pointer to the
>   resolved_path.
>
> Otherwise, it returns NULL, the contents of the array resolved_path
>   are undefined, and errno is set to indicate the error.

In other words, use the `fs.realpath` method to return the resolved path (actual directory path) and then compare against the path returned from the `fs.readdir` method. If the values are different, the path returned from `fs.readdir` is a "fake" path.

In the case of the O.P., `fs.realpath` returned "*C:\Programme*" which resolved to "*C:\Program Files*" when using `fs.realpath`.

See the comment by @CherryDT to the O.P. describing why `isSymbolicLink` returned false.